# how can i format json Date Time data to my needs

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I use json data in my windows phone app and i get an string named dt_txt from the website which i want to format like i need it, so far it shows me 2013-11-18 21:00:00 i need it in HH:mm  day:month:year format like 21:00 18.11.2013 how can i get this?

i bind this string to an textblock in my app and i tried to change the stringformat to another value but it shows alwasy the same

here is the code of the textblock how i set it:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].dt_txt}"/>
```

but it always shows me first the years then the month then the day and hours minutes and second. for european standards i dont need this. i need just the clock and then the date like 19.11.2013

this i use in my model to make this downloaded text to an string:

```
public string sati
    {
        get
        {
            return dt_txt.ToString();
        }
    }
```

how to manipulate this to show the downloaded date from 2013-11-24 12:00:00 to something more natural like 24.11. or 24.11.2013 or even the DayOfWeek like lets say "Sunday", or how to cut the date out and leave only the time value there? so it would be only 12:00 instead of the whole string 2013-11-24 12:00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].dt_txt, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" />
```

Comment: i tried this too but it still shows me 2013-11-19 00:00:00. i think it has something to do that is downloaded like this.

i get this string from this api. http://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?Q=new%20York&units=metric

you can have a look if you want i deserialize this json data and all is fine but just the date is somehow not editable

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking this will only work if you are binding to a datetime.  You may need to datetime.parse the string then bind

Comment: yeah but how, this is how i define my DateTime in the "Model" of my mvvm setup:

`private int _dt;

        public int dt
        {
            get { return _dt; }
            set
            {
                _dt = value;
                var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                Time = epoch.AddSeconds(value);
            }
        }


        private DateTime _time;

        public DateTime Time
        {
            get { return _time; }
            set { _time = value; }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use toolkit's datetimeformatter